# How to load XAML with images using XamlReader.Load method?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, xamlreader

- Is it possible to load XAML file with images from stream into WPF
  application?
- And how to store this images in the files?

I've tried `<x:code>` part, but `XamlReader.Load` method can't process it.

XAML Code:

```
    <Page x:Class="System.Windows.Controls.Page"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Loaded="onLoaded"
>
<Canvas Width="500" Height="1000">
</Canvas>
<x:Code>
<![CDATA[
void onLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
Canvas cvs= this.Content as Canvas;
Image img = new Image();
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
string image64 = "...base64image...";
byte[] bd = Convert.FromBase64String(image64);
bi.StreamSource = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bd);
bi.EndInit();
img.Source = bi;
Thickness margin = img.Margin;
margin.Left = 10;
margin.Top = 20; 
img.Margin = margin;
cvs.Children.Add(img);
}
]]>
</x:Code>
</Page>
```

C# code:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\...\XAML\img_xaml.xaml", FileMode.Open);

            Window w = new Window();

            object xaml = XamlReader.Load(fs);
            w.Content = xaml;
            w.Show();
```

Exception -

> Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll

Comment: WPF isn't UWP. XamlReader.Load is for loading XAML, not images. If you search for "wpf load image" and "wpf save image" you'll find stuff.

Comment: But I need to load embedded in the XAML-file images.

Comment: Please paste the actual XAML into your question. Also the C# code where you're calling `XamlReader.Load()`. [See MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).